# ReactJS Router - React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get ReactRouter setup to build a Single Page Application with ReactJS. I am having an issue setting up the Router though.

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

This is my code.

```
'use strict';

const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
const ReactRouter = require('react-router')
const when = require('when');

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>TEST PAGE</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

var Router = ReactRouter;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Route.RountHandler;

var routes = (
    <Route name="root" handler="{App}" path="/">
        <Route handler={Test} path="test" />
    </Route>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Router>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('react'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-router v1.0 or higher, `handler` has been deprecated. Try using `component` instead:

```
var routes = (
    <Route name="root" component="{App}" path="/">
        <Route component={Test} path="test" />
    </Route>
)
```

Here is upgrade guide referencing [RouteHandler](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/c27b018268864c8671c4cc3c6c6819bb255114df/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#routehandler)